# Log4j notifying on logging level changes

Tags: java, log4j

Is there anyway , or any configuration in log4j that tell him to log a line whenever some "logging level" configurations occur ?

I mean someone changed in some package the debug level from INFO to DEBUG , I want that event being logged by log4j.

Thanks

Comment: Changing a log level on a package is usually done in the log4j.xml.  The app would have to be re-deployed.  I don't think it'd be a runtime event.

Comment: Wrong .. you can configure it to be uddated in runtime , log4j.properties or log4j.xml

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's your case, but if you are reloading the configuration file using `configureAndWatch` you should be able to see the information you need setting the system property `-Dlog4j.debug=true`.

See 
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a LogLog, the self logging of Log4J. I have never used it but if the solution exists it is there. I'd suggest you to download the source code of log4j and try to investigate it where it "knows" that the log level is being changed. Once you found the code see whether it prints something to self log and configure it as you need.

I'd be appreciate if you can post here more concrete answer if you find it. Good luck.

Comment: There is a setInternalDebugging(boolean) method in this class. it may give you but you want, but a lot more to go with it. There will be a performance hit for turning on this much logging. Other then that, the class acts just like Logger

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, if you have a servlet, jsp or a screen on your application where you are able to change log levels, you will most likely be doing something like this

```
public void changeLogLevel(String className, String logLevel){
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
    Level level = Level.toLevel(logLevel);
    logger.setLevel(level);
}
```

in order to log this event, all you would have to do is add an extra logger statement for this event

```
private static Logger classLogger = Logger.getLogger(ThisClass.class);
public void changeLogLevel(String className, String logLevel){
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
    Level level = Level.toLevel(logLevel);
    logger.setLevel(level);
    classLogger.debug("The Level of " + className + " has changed to " + logLevel);
}
```

Then each time a log level occurs, you can log it here. If you want to get fancy, just send this log to its own file. You may want to advance the method even further to include an IP/username of the user who changed the log level.

If you have control over your application, ensure this is your only point in the application where a user can change your logging levels.

Comment: No that was not that i meant. The log level is set from the properties and xml file. Log4j has an automatic listener on that file

Comment: In the case of a listener, it should be looking for a new timestamp on the file, and if a new version is found, it will wipe your previous config in memory and load the new file. I doubt it would be on a line by line basis.  In that case, each line is "new". I doubt you will be able to capture exactly what changed unless you turn on log4j debug (log4j.configDebug flag). You may want to update your original question to show how you are configuring your Log4j as there are many ways to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but the built-in java.util.logging.LogManager implementation has an addPropertyChangeListener() method that does exactly what you want.

I couldn't find anything comparable in Log4J, but I didn't look that hard...